# What's the promise chaining equivalent of awaiting multiple async functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, chaining

I'm studying the usage of promsies and async/await.

I've wrote the following code, which does the following:

1. It gets some database's data (using Knex.js),
2. Handles that data,
3. Assigns the handled data into a specified property.

These 3 steps are done multiple times (In the following code, it's done twice), and are always `await`ed:

```
async function run() {
   return await getData();
}
async function getData() {
    let handledData = {};
    handledData.res1 = await knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '1')
                                 .then(data => handleData(data))
                                 .catch(handleError);
    handledData.res2 = await knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '2')
                                 .then(data => handleData(data, handledData))
                                 .catch(handleError);
    return handledData;
}
async function handleData(data) {
    let res = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
        res.push(item.column1);
    });
    return res; 
}
function handleError (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write the promise-chaining equivalent of `getData`, and this is what I came up with:

```
async function getData() {
    let handledData = {};
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, error){ resolve(); });
    promise
    .then(function () {
        return knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '1')
                    .then(data => handleData(data))
                    .catch(handleError);
    })
    .then(function(handled){
        handledData.res1 = handled;
        return knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '2')
                    .then(data => handleData(data))
                    .catch(handleError);
    })
    .then(function(handled){
        handledData.res2 = handled;
        return handledData;
    })
    .catch(handleError);
    return promise;
}
```

But this doesn't quite work. What happens is that after the first `then` returns, the `await` inside `run` ends its awaiting, which causes `run` to return - and only then the second `then` is executed.

How can I make the promise-chaining version work as the multiple-await version does?

(and please, feel free to point out any misunderstaings I made of promises/async-await)

Comment: Do you *need* to use `await` or sequential requests? It might be better to use `Promise.all` (parallel requests, not serial requests)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, that's a good idea, I'll do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I'd recommend using `Promise.all` instead, it'll make your script run faster in addition to making the logic clearer:

```
const getData = Promise.all([
  knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '1')
    // Simply pass the function name as a parameter to the `.then`:
    .then(handleData)
    .catch(handleError),
  knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '2')
    .then(handleData)
    .catch(handleError)
])
  .then(([res1, res1]) => ({ res1, res2 }));
```

Comment: I like this much better than running the queries in order since thy don't depend on each other.

Answer (score 1):

`knex.select().then()` returns a promise, so you don't need to wrap it in another promise you just need to set up the chain of `then()`s and return the whole thing. The result will be that `getData` returns the promise from the last then. You can return the value you want from that `then()` which will make it available to the caller. For example:

```
function run() {
    getData()
    .then(handledData => console.log(handledData) /* do something with data */)
}

function getData() {
    let handledData = {};
    // need to return this promise to callers can access it
    return knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '1')
    .then(data => handledData.res1 = handleData(data))
    .then(() => knex.select('column1').from('table1').where('column1', '2'))
    .then(data => {
        handledData.res2 = handleData(data)
        return handledData
    })
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

You could also set this up to pass the `handledData` object thought the chain, but you don't need to in this case.

The function `handleData()` is synchronous, so you don't need to make it an async function.

Comment: Thanks. 2 questions: (1) Wouldn't `run` return immediately (as opposed to awaiting it on my original code)? (2) I used wrapping to make the code structured, so that each `then` contains a query and handlers (i.e., a `then` and a `catch`). Your suggestion makes them "alternating": One `then` makes the query, and the other handles its results, and so forth (think of a case where there are more than two queries). Don't you find it less structured/clean?

Comment: @HeyJude Yes, `run()` will start immediately - the code in `then` will be what waits for the query to finish. It something is going to call `run()` you should `return getData().then()` this will return a promise, just like your async function does. The structure here still has a `then() for each query. The second select does use anything returned from the first, it's just chained so it runs in order like your `async` version does. I personally much prefer the `async` version, but would probably try to run both queries at the same time since they don't depend on each other.